# Special \cref display for \externaldocument

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, xr

I am using cleveref pointing to equations within my document, as well as to a technical appendix in a separate file (loaded by \externaldocument)

**Setup**

Lets that the the first file was in `main.tex`, compiled, etc.

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}     
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\begin{document}
    \section{MyTitle}\label{sec:mytitle}            
    \subsection{MySub}\label{sec:sub}
\begin{equation}
A = b\label{eq:ab}
\end{equation}
  \end{document}
```

And another file references this, compiled after `main`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[main:]{main} %Loads a doc for external
\begin{document}
    \section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}
       \begin{equation}
       B = C\label{eq:bc}
       \end{equation} 
     local ref: \cref{sec:mysection}, external ref: \cref{main:sec:mytitle} and \cref{main:sec:sub}\\
     local eq ref: \cref{eq:bc}, external ref: \cref{main:eq:ab}
\end{document}
```

**Question:**
The above should work, but while reading there is no way for me to know if a reference is to the external (technical appendix) in my case, or to an internal link.

Is there any way to have `\cref` conditionally change the text if a file is external (e.g. set something up so that if the refered label begins with `main:` then add a `Main` to the beginning of the title, etc.)  That technique should work for sections, propositions, figures, but perhaps not for equations, which have the form `(1)` in this setup.  Ideally this would show up as `Main (1)` or `(Main 1)`... whichever works, though I think the latter is a little clearer.

---

**Extention with `xr-hyper`**
Something different will be necessary to get this to work with the related `xr-hyper` and `hyperref` packages.  I don't care of the hyperlinks actually work between documents or not, the test is:

In file `main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\crefname{equation}{}{}     
\begin{document}
\section{MyTitle}\label{sec:mytitle}            
\begin{equation}
  A = b\label{eq:ab}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

and in the separate file:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\externaldocument[main:]{main1}    
\begin{document}    
\section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}    
\begin{equation}
  B = C\label{eq:bc}
\end{equation}     
Local ref: \cref{sec:mysection}, external ref: \cref{main:sec:mytitle}    
Local eq ref: \cref{eq:bc}, external ref: \cref{main:eq:ab}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

this adds the same prefix (eg `main:`) to cleverref's able type as used for the label so the refence is of type `main:section` rather than `section` and then you can use

```
\Crefname{main:section}{\TR-section}{\TR-main-sections}%
```

to specify the format for that type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{xr}
\makeatletter
\long\def\XR@test#1#2#3#4\XR@{%
  \ifx#1\newlabel
    \xr@cref#2@cref\relax#3\@nil
  \else\ifx#1\@input
     \edef\XR@list{\XR@list#2\relax}%
  \fi\fi
  \ifeof\@inputcheck\expandafter\XR@aux
  \else\expandafter\XR@read\fi}

\def\xr@@cref{@cref}
\def\xr@cr@add#1{{[\XR@prefix\@gobble#1}}
\def\xr@cref#1@cref#2\relax#3\@nil{%
\def\tmp{#2}%
\ifx\tmp\xr@@cref
  \edef\tmp{\noexpand\newlabel{\XR@prefix#1@cref}{\xr@cr@add#3}}%
  \tmp
\else
 \newlabel{\XR@prefix#1}{#3}%
\fi
}
\makeatother
  \protected\def\TR{TR}% hide from lowercase
 \Crefname{main:section}{\TR-section}{\TR-main-sections}%
\externaldocument[main:]{maindoc} %Loads a doc for external
\begin{document}
    \section{My section}\label{sec:mysection}
    Linking to \cref{main:sec:mytitle} or internally \cref{sec:mysection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps.  I posted an implementation above.  At this point, the only thing messing me up is that I need to have equations referenced by (1) as is done in \cref through `\crefname{equation}{}{}`.  But I couldn't figure out how to get the () to appear.  e.g. would like it to say `Main (1)` instead of just `Main 1`.  Any ideas?

Comment: @jlperla (it's not really the site style to put answers into the question, better to add a notnother answer)  you just need to look in cleverref see what it does for equations... I don't know the package at all but it seems to have `\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}%` which puts the `()` in  so I guess you need something similar  for main:equation

Comment: Thank you, and sorry to break style.  I edited the question to extend my use case for equations a little bit.  I will try out your technique in the comment.l  Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to adapt your code to the `\creflabelformat{equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}%` but I fear it is outside of my competence...

Comment: @jlperla I just added this and it seemed to work: `\Crefname{main:equation}{\TR-equation}{\TR-equations}
 \creflabelformat{main:equation}{\textup{(#2#1#3)}}`

Comment: Hmm... I overthought it.  I think this finished this, thank you!

Comment: Carlise I realized that this technique works great with just created, but fails with xr-hyperref and hyperref. Is the site style to post a completely new question, or to make an addendum to this one. The question is otherwise identical.

Comment: @jlperla Probably needs an extra two {}{} adding somewhere I'll look later (i'm not sure exactly what hyperef does to cref but usually it's just extra groups carrying the information hyperref needs, may be this evening)

Comment: thank you so much.  I made the addendum to extentions to the question with the baseline packages that would be needed.

Comment: I played around with this a bit, and it looks like I need to replace one of your lines above with `\edef\tmp{\noexpand\newlabel{\XR@prefix#1@cref}{\xr@cr@add#3}{}{}}%`  ... but I could have made a mistake.  Seems to compile.

Comment: Sorry, one last thing:  I think it is all working within my doucment.  HOWEVER: when I add all of the non file-specific text between the  makeatletter and makeatother the it to  .sty package directly, or by putting in a new `\def` with it, then it compiles, but none of formatting works.  Is there some sort of latex scoping I am missing?

Comment: @jlperla hard to say, but don't put the `\makeat...` commands into a .sty file (`@` is already a letter there)

Comment: thank you.  I tried that, moved it to a completely separate package, and loaded it as late as I could.  Seemed to work.  But I found one issue with the implementation:  It works with `\section{}` but not with `\subsection{}`, etc.  Is there a fix that would get this to work with subsection and subsubsection?  Thanks for all your time on this.

Comment: I wasn't sure the best protocol for an extension, so I posted my quetsion about subsections separately in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247356/special-cref-display-for-sections-and-subsections-in-external-documents  If you think that is repetitive, I can remove it - but the test case is clean.